# How can I format an oracle query with this date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried various alterations to get the right query date format. Below is one of them.
The below date is actually filled in by string substitution from a java program. I need to be able to interpret it and run the query. Currently the query fails with the below error:

```
[Error] Execution (48: 18): ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

SELECT 
 to_date('Mon Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 1990', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS')
 FROM
 duAL
```

Comment: Do you understad that the second argument is intended to represent the elements of the date string, and that what you've said here is that the year ("yyyy") is "Mon "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use to_date for timezone. try this.

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('MON JAN 01 12:00:00 EST 1990', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')
FROM
duAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I try, removed the **Mon** and **EST**

```
SELECT to_date('Jan 01 12:00:00 1990', 'MON DD HH:MI:SS RRRR') FROM dual
```

Answer (score -1):

[**EDIT**] Fixed the error, use [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions202.htm#SQLRF06143) it should work.

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 1990', 'DY MON dd HH:MI:SS TZR yyyy')
FROM
duAL
```